# Need to make div a rollover for image within (using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rollover

alright so i have some unique problems; first of all, my jquery is not working; i very well might have not put it in the html right so i am going to toss a good deal of code out to see;

basically i need the rollover class image to change to its hover state when the div class is rolled-over (i have a some css which changes the div class display to block) alright so here is the html

```
<div id="header">
<div class="home" id="home" ><a href="index.html"><p><img src="images/home-crown.png" class="rollover" width="100px" /></p></a></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/load-it-up.js"></script>
```

/so yeah... trying to swap that image stuff out here is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("img.rollover").hover(
      function() 
        {this.src = this.src.replace("images/home-crown.png","images/home-crown-hover.png");},
      function() 
        {this.src = this.src.replace("images/home-crown-hover.png","images/home-crown.png");}
 ); 
});
```

really frustrated with it because i have tried multiple solutions; any help at all would be appreciated; it is probably something stupid :P

right now i am just trying to get the image to rollover (at least)
i really want the rollover to activate when the div is rolled over (the #home div)

Comment: can't you just do the attribute
`$(this).attr("src","home-crown.png");`

and vice versa

Comment: @Daniel where at? (as in after what code?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("img.rollover").hover(
   function(){
      $(this).attr("src","images/home-crown-hover.png");
   },
   function(){
      $(this).attr("src","images/home-crown.png");
   }
);
```

Comment: something like that should work, it just isn't, i guess i will rummage through the code...

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to include the `images/` part in the url.

Comment: no i got those; well thanks for the help it must be my mistake in the long area of the code